# way to determine best number of clusters weka

Tags: clustering, weka

When using weka library for clustering ,Is there any way to find best number of clusters.
The EM methods are defined but how to use these methods in java code.
Please suggest

Comment: So that this can be made into an answerable question, please tell us what *you* mean by "best."

Answer (score 4):

I like to determine it based on a hypothesis. Take a look at the dataset, then keep in mind the hypothesis you have of the data.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options:

1. The number of clusters is provided by some training data.
2. You determine an appropriate number of clusters based on some hypothesis.
3. As a rule of thumb, you can use k = (n / 2) ^ 0.5 where n = number of data points and is number of cluster.

See:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467225/ideal-number-of-clusters-in-weka-k-means
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determining_the_number_of_clusters_in_a_data_set

Comment: Thanks For Your Reply.But I have one query that by using this formula may be we will not be able to get best number of cluster.Is there any way to find best number of cluster.Please suggest.